# Auditwheel ELF alignment error on shared library

Tags: python, cython, fftw, python-manylinux

I have a Cython project that is pulling in FFTW. When I build my project with

`python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

and then import the generated .so from python it runs just fine. But when I try to build a wheel with

`auditwheel repair --plat manylinux2014_x86_64 dist/<package>.whl -w wheelhouse/`

and upload the resultant .whl in wheelhouse/ to our hosted pypi the resulting wheel doesn't work after installation. When I try to import it I get the error that:

`ImportError: libfftw3-<sha>.so.3.3.2: ELF load command address/offset not properly aligned`

Inspecting the whl it is neat that `auditwheel` seems to copy the FFTW .so library into it (I believe a stripped version). That *would* be great, if it worked.

Note that this is on the same machine, it's just the difference between using the built .so versus creating the .whl and uploading it and then pip installing it.

Am I doing something wrong? Are there options on `auditwheel` I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

It's embarassing the answer was this simple, but it seems like if I add `--strip` to the auditwheel command it works fine:

`auditwheel repair --strip --plat manylinux2014_x86_64 dist/<package>.whl -w wheelhouse/`

Alternatively, I also found that I could exclude the fftw library from the auditwheel package and just rely on the system package manager having it installed. I don't like that as much because I don't know how to enforce an external dependency like that for a python package.

`auditwheel repair --exclude libfftw3.so.3 --plat manylinux2014_x86_64 dist/<package>.whl -w wheelhouse/`

It was a bit of a pain to find the right exclude parameter, I had to use `objdump` on the .so to see it had the major version number on it.